# How can I map an Enum using Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API?

Tags: .net, enums, entity-framework-4.1

I've gotten somewhat lost between the sheets of EF... Like the rest of the free world, I really have a need to use Enums in my POCOs. Like many I talk to, I would thoroughly enjoy mapping Enums using code only because, well I just don't like pictures all that much.

My quandary here is that I am getting conflicting information on nearly every article I pull up. It gets even harder sifting out the custom implementations or "extensions" people have published to try and work around the EF shortfall.

The [EF June CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394151.aspx) announces support for Enums and Spatial Types but it appears that support only comes when using the designer? And also, is the June CTP part of the EF 4.1 Update 1 or still not RTM?

If there's a way to support Enums using the Fluent API, I would be indebted to anyone who can help me out or steer me in the right direction!

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums are not supported by current EF version. They are supported in June 2011 CTP for both EDMX and code mapping but that CTP doesn't have production version - it is not part of EF 4.1 Update 1 or upcomming EF 4.2. Imho if we will be very lucky it will be part of .NET 4.5.

The easiest way to use enums now is using two properties: mapped int and non mapped enum property converting from mapped int:

```
public class Test
{
    public int EnumValue { get; set; }
    public EnumType Value 
    {
        get { return (EnumType)EnumValue; }
        set { EnumValue = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

You cannot use enums in Linq to entities queries when using this approach.

Comment: Maybe need a [NotMapped] annotation on that second prop?

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, I was afraid that was going to be the answer.. Sad panda. Guess I'll just have to hope for 4.5; in the meantime do you or anyone else know if there's a way to do it in such a way that Linq to Entities will work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Enum is not support in EF at this stage. The latest 4.2 release only has bug fixes. Seem like Enum support will be in EF 5 which will come out with .Net 4.5. Please read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/67a9247e-eccf-4b14-9da1-db630e408ae8