# EF 4.1 what is the best way to use enums and be able to query them on columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Here I have my code, but I wonder if this will leave me do easy queries against the enum columns.

By the way, do you see something else I can improve in this code?

```
public class HRContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantImage> ApplicantImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantPosition> ApplicantsPositions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationPositionHistory> ApplicationsPositionHistory { get; set; }
    }

    public class HRContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<HRContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(HRContext context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int yearsExperienceRequired { get; set; }
    }

    public class Applicant
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string skypeuser { get; set; }
        public ApplicantImage photo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicantImage
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }    
    }

    public class ApplicantPosition
    {
        public Position appliedPosition { get; set; }
        public Applicant applicant { get; set; }
        public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }
        public int StatusValue { get; set; }

        public Status Status
        {
            get { return (Status)StatusValue; }
            set { StatusValue = (int)value; }
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationPositionHistory
    {
        public ApplicantPosition applicantPosition { get; set; }
        public Status oldStatus { get; set; }
        public Status newStatus { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        Applied,
        AcceptedByHR,
        AcceptedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByHR,
        InterviewedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByGeneralManager,
        AcceptedByGeneralManager,
        NotAccepted
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I map an Enum using Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490530/how-can-i-map-an-enum-using-entity-framework-4-1-fluent-api)

Comment: if you read that answer there, it says: You cannot use enums in Linq to entities queries when using this approach. Thats exactly what I asked here, whats the workaround to be able to make queries using the enum columns?

Comment: You need to use the `int` field in LINQ queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use enums in queries (it is only possible with [June 2011 CTP)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx). The closest to using enums in queries is when using [Enum wrappers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx).

Comment: EF 4.1 was released on march, EF 4.2 is going to be released soon, they say it will support enums on 4.2 (its a release candidate)

Comment: EF 4.2 was already released but it doesn't contain anything from that CTP because ADO.NET team changed versioning. It is not know where next CTP or RTM with enum supports will be released.

Comment: Indeed I just read this comment; The June 2011 CTP was our first attempt to release a full version of Entity Framework, including its core libraries, outside of the .NET Framework. Unfortunately, we encountered technical difficulties that severely affect the customer experience in doing so  In the end we realized that our best option was to ship the next version of the core libraries of EF as part of .NET 4.5. Therefore new features that like enum and spatial type support require the updates to the core libraries will have to wait until .NET 4.5.

Comment: I haven't install .NET 4.5 yet but as I know new EF features where not mentioned in "What's new in .NET 4.5". Hopefully they will really be released in .NET 4.5.